# How to put values of buttons in an array of TextViews in Android

Tags: android

I have 6 `Button`s and 6 `TextView`s that was put in 2 different arrays. what I want to do is when I click a `Button` the value of the `Button` will be set on the first `TextView` and the next `Button` I click will be set on the next `TextView` and so on. I don't know the right way to do this. I know the code below was wrong since I set the 'x' to '0' but I'm stuck so please help.

```
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);    
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);             
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);


    btn1.setText("A");
    btn2.setText("M");
    btn3.setText("O");
    btn4.setText("N");  
    btn5.setText("L");
    btn6.setText("S");
    submit.setText("Submit");
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    final TextView[] textView = new TextView[6];
        textView[0] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        textView[1] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);
        textView[2] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t3);
        textView[3] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t4);
        textView[4] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t5);
        textView[5] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t6);
    final Button button[] = new Button[6];
        button[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        button[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        button[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        button[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        button[5] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);



   int x=0;   
   for(int i = 0; i <6; i++){
 if (button[i].getId() == v.getId()){
     textView[x].setText(button[i].getText());
 }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try `textView[i].setText(button[i].getText());`

Comment: @MysticMagic but if i first click button[5] it will be set on textView[5]. what i'm trying to do is when i click any button i want it to be set on textView[0]. for example i clicked button[5] first it should be set on textView[0] and next if i click button[3] it should be on textView[1].

Comment: wait i will try on my machine and update you

Comment: Pls see my answer its working fine as i checked on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Initialize x as a global variable.

```
int x=0; // in onCreate instead of onClick
```

And change code in onClick as

```
for(int i = 0; i <6; i++){
    if (button[i].getId() == v.getId()){
        textView[x].setText(button[i].getText());
        if(x<6)
            x++;
        else
        {
            //You will have to think of logic in case any button is clicked second time after 6 clicks.
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this gives a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i <6; i++){
 if (button[i].getId() == v.getId()){
     textView[i].setText(button[i].getText());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls use this code as i checked your problem on my machine and this code doing fine.

#### Use this code:--

```
final TextView[] textView = new TextView[6];
Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6;
int counter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.que);

    textView[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    textView[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    textView[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t3);
    textView[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t4);
    textView[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t5);
    textView[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t6);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);

}
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (counter >= 6) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn1:
        textView[counter++].setText(btn1.getText().toString());
        break;
    case R.id.btn2:
        textView[counter++].setText(btn2.getText().toString());
        break;
    case R.id.btn3:
        textView[counter++].setText(btn3.getText().toString());
        break;
    case R.id.btn4:
        textView[counter++].setText(btn4.getText().toString());
        break;
    case R.id.btn5:
        textView[counter++].setText(btn5.getText().toString());
        break;
    case R.id.btn6:
        textView[counter++].setText(btn6.getText().toString());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```